# A problem was found with the configuration of task ':react-native-bootsplash:compileDebugShaders' (type 'ShaderCompile')

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, gradle

I am facing this issue for 2 days but nothing I have got, there is no specific answer or any article for this error also i am still confused about where to find these files in the android folder or in another file structure,pls help me out thanks in advance

A problem was found with the configuration of task ':react-native-bootsplash:compileDebugShaders' (type 'ShaderCompile').

- In plugin 'com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidBasePlugin' type 'com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ShaderCompile' property 'sourceDir' is annotated with
  @InputFiles but missing a normalization strategy.

  Reason: If you don't declare the normalization, outputs can't be re-used between machines or locations on the same machine, therefore caching efficiency drops significantly.

  Possible solution: Declare the normalization strategy by annotating the property with either @PathSensitive, @Classpath or @CompileClasspath.